# Get controller Link with @RequestMapping value from properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller below, with `api.prefix` is set from a properties file.

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;
...

@RequestMapping("/${api.prefix}/test")
public class ApiRestController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/one", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    HttpEntity<?> collect(@RequestBody ApiRequestBody input) {
        ...
        linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).data(input.id)).withSelfRel();
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> data(@PathVariable String instrumentId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Suppose `api.prefix=/v234` is set on the properties file. The problem is when I request to `/v234/test/one`, the `methodOn(Class)` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` with message `Map has no value for \'api.prefix\'`;

But if I set `@RequestMapping("/v234/test")`, it works fine.

Comment: Just to make sure your properties file is being read correctly, I would add to the class another private member - `private String prefix` and put an annotation `@Value("${api.prefix}")` on it. This will make sure the properties file is configured correctly. Perhaps you'll find the properties file is not in the class path or you have a type or something.

Comment: That won't work, as the builder will introspect the class and not the mappings. So this solution will not work.

Comment: @Avi The properties file is fine since the app is working without `linkTo(methodOn(...))`. I just try to implement HATEOAS on the RESTapi.

Comment: @M.Deinum That what I expected. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comments. Did you try what I suggested and it didn't work? Because there's no reason it wouldn't work, I just try to make sure it's not some classpath issues with the properties file.

Comment: @Morilla Thaisa can you try removing `.` from your key, try using `_` isntead, Make changes both in properties files and `@RequestMapping("/${api_prefix}/test")`

Comment: It won't work... The resource support uses reflection to analyze the class, the class doesn't change and the `@RequestMapping` still contains the `${your.prop}` (as it comes from the plain class file). The Web MVC stuff does some processing on the detected URL's so that it replaces things in memory but there is no way to change the actual class file. None the less I think you shouldn't be using properties to specify the URL... But that is another matter.

Comment: Well not entirely true, you could pass in a property value for the path, although that would make you an URL including the $. Which in turn you would need to strip.

Comment: Property-files should be used, only for environment specific parameters. Are you sure you want a different api prefix in dev and prod? Probably not. Just use a constant instead. This constant can be used in your RequestMappings!

Comment: Ok thanks @M. Deinum, yes I think I shouldn't.